# How to structure a function with a file and a malloc

Tags: c, file, function, malloc

If a I have a function that works with a file and a pointer, like this:

```
int funzione (int *vet)
{
    FILE *fin;

    if ( !(fin = fopen(name, "r")) )
        return 1;

    /* read informations from file (like num) */

    vet = (int *) malloc (num*sizeof(int));

    /* ... */

    return fclose(fin); 
}
```

How can I return `vet`?
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to return it ?

Comment: Because I want to use it in `main()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return it via other than the return value itself, you can simply pass in a *double* pointer and dereference that.

C is strictly pass-by-value (everything given to a function is a *copy* of the original and changes to it won't be reflected back to the caller) but you can emulate pass-by-reference with pointers. You would be looking at something like:

```
int funzione (int **pVet)
{
    FILE *fin;

    if ( !(fin = fopen(name, "r")) )
        return 1;

    /* read informations from file (like num) */

    *pVet = malloc (num * sizeof(int));

    /* ... */

    return fclose(fin); 
}
```

and you would call it thus:

```
int *myVet;
int result = funzione (&myVet);
```

You'll notice I've also removed the cast on return from `malloc` - it's a bad idea to do this in C since it can hide certain subtle errors.

You shouldn't make the mistake of thinking, because you're passing in an `int` pointer, that it will reflect back. If it was the `int` you wanted to change, that would be okay. But, since it's the `int` *pointer* you want to change, you need a pointer to *that.*

---

However, keep in mind that a common method of returning an error where pointers are involved is simply to return NULL. Whether that's suitable in your case is something you have to decide. If possible, I would consider returning the pointer itself and using NULL as an indication that the data wasn't obtainable (couldn't open file, couldn't allocate memory, data was wrong somehow, couldn't close file and so on).

That would go something like:

```
int *funzione (void) {
    FILE *fin = fopen(name, "r");
    if (fin == NULL) return NULL;

    /* read informations from file (like num) */

    int *pVet = malloc (num * sizeof(int));
    if (pVet == NULL) return NULL;

    // Populate pVet as needed. Any error must free it before
    //   returning NULL, such as with:

    if (fclose(fin) != 0) {
        free (pVet);
        return NULL;
    }

    return pVet;
}
```

Comment: @user: it's `int *myVet`, you may have seen it mid-edit.

Comment: For the last part of your answer: then I must change `if ( !(fin = fopen(name, "r")) ) return 1;` into `if ( !(fin = fopen(name, "r")) ) return 0;`and `return fclose(fin);` into `return !fclose(fin);` ?

Comment: For the main answer: but `malloc()` returns a new pointer value, right? Why if I use a double pointer I can overtake this problem?

Comment: @user, if you're asking why your original code won't work, it's because assigning to `vet` won't be reflected back to the caller. In the function, `vet` in the function is a _copy_ of whatever you passed in. Added some more explanation to hopefully clarify.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand! Only one thing: `return NULL;` is the same of `return 0;`?

Comment: @user, as of C99 at least (see section 6.2.3.2/3), `0` is treated as a null pointer constant in the code, much like C++. At some point prior to that, it _may_ not have been guaranteed to work in all implementations.

Comment: But if I wrote `if(NULL)` it works in all implementation like `if(0)` or not?

Comment: @user, since that's a totally _different_ question, it really should be asked as such. That way, you'll get a much broader response, and it will be more likely to help others in future. From what I've seen in the standard, 0 can be used for the null pointer. Going the other way may not be so easy, you would have to examine the implicit conversions in the standard.. My own advice would be to use NULL for pointers and 0 for integers. It'll make your code much cleaner.

Comment: _You'll notice I've also removed the cast on return from malloc - it's a bad idea to do this in C since it can hide certain subtle errors._ Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 1):

One option is to define a struct that holds onto the FILE* and the integer array you want to return.

You could define something like:

```
 struct funzione_result {
   int fclose_result;
   int *vet;
 }
```

And then assign to each member in your function.  You'll still need to remember to free the vet array.